# How to determine the return type of an overloaded function?

Tags: c++

In the code below, how can I determine the return types of both `f` overloads without instantiating `A` and `B`?

```
class A
{
public:

    A(std::string k) : key(k)
    {
    }

private:

    std::string key;
};

class B
{
public:

    B(int k) : key(k)
    {
    }

private:

    int key;
};

int f(const A&);
std::string f(const B&);

// It is possible to determine the return types as follows:
using a_return_type = decltype(f(A{ "" }));
using b_return_type = decltype(f(B{0}));
```

Pseudo-code solution:

```
using a_return_type = std::invoke_result_t<f, A>;
using b_return_type = std::invoke_result_t<f, B>;
```

**EDIT1**

I need a solution without `A{ "" }` and `B{0}`. Assume I do not know what the `A` and `B` constructors are.

**EDIT2**

At least it is possible, with the code below:

```
A* p_a = nullptr;
B* p_b = nullptr;
using a_return_type = decltype(f(*p_a));
using b_return_type = decltype(f(*p_b));
```

but obviously it is not the best coding style.

or

```
using a_return_type = decltype(f(*static_cast<A*>(nullptr)));
using b_return_type = decltype(f(*static_cast<B*>(nullptr)));
```

Comment: @user12002570 I need a code without `A{ "" }` and `B{0}`,  assume I do not know what constructors A and B have.

Comment: !@AlexeyStarinsky That should have been mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of "XY problem"? Please provide your reasons for changing a working solution to NOT do something and describe the goal you really want to solve by doing this. That way, people can figure out methods to achieve what you are trying to do, without doing it the way you imagine that it could be done. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You ask a question and provide the answer. Then, after prompting, you clarify that the answer you gave is not the one you want. After further prompting (via an "impossible" answer) you provide a nother solution, which does work. I think I will give you time to ask a question according to [ask] and maybe read up on the xy-problem concept. Good luck.

Comment: `*p_a` dereferencing a null pointer?

Comment: @user12002570 No since it is not evaluated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want an object of type `A` or `B` in an unevaluated context without actually knowing how to construct an `A` or `B`. This is exactly what [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is for:

```cpp
using a_return_type = decltype(f(std::declval<A>()));
using b_return_type = decltype(f(std::declval<B>()));
```